# How to fix error: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for https://my_account.snowflakecomputing.com/?

Tags: java, driver, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, talend

I have this code:

```
package routines;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Properties;

public class SnowflakeDriverExample {

    public static void main() throws Exception
    {
     System.out.println("Create JDBC connection");
     Connection connection = getConnection();
     System.out.println("Done creating JDBC connectionn");
    }

    private static Connection getConnection()
           throws SQLException
    {
     try
     {
       Class.forName("net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver");
     }
     catch (ClassNotFoundException ex)
     {
      System.err.println("Driver not found");
     }
     // build connection properties
     Properties properties = new Properties();
     properties.put("user", "my_user");
     properties.put("password", "my_password");
     properties.put("db", "my_db");
     properties.put("schema", "my_schema");

     // create a new connection
     String connectStr = System.getenv("SF_JDBC_CONNECT_STRING");
     // use the default connection string if it is not set in environment
     if(connectStr == null)
     {
      connectStr = "https://my_account.snowflakecomputing.com/";
     }
     return DriverManager.getConnection(connectStr, properties);
    }
}
```

now, when I call:

```
SnowflakeDriverExample.main();
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in component tJava_1 (j_example)
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for https://my_account.snowflakecomputing.com/
```

when I iterated over drivers and printed them- I got this one:

```
net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver
```

looks like I have the correct snowflake driver, and I the connectionStr is my actual snowflake url.
so what's the problem?

Comment: You have a database that communicates via the https protocol? That connection string doesn't look quite right.

Comment: There's a pretty detailed explanation on how to correctly use the driver [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-configure.html).

Comment: You need to use a jdbc connection string. The one you mentioned is some HTTP url that you're thinking might have the database.

Answer (score 2):

ok.
the problem was my connectionStr, which was:

```
connectStr = "https://my_account.snowflakecomputing.com/";
```

and should be:

```
connectStr = "jdbc:snowflake://my_account.snowflakecomputing.com/";
```

now everything is fine. thanks a lot!